# Why readings for WiFi link speed and bandwidth don't correlate?

Tags: android, networking, kotlin, wifi, android-wifi

I want to get the "speed" for my WiFi connection.

From `NetworkCapabilities` class, I get:

```
Link downstream bandwidth: 1048576 Kbps
Link upstream bandwidth:   1048576 Kbps
```

However, using `WiFiInfo` class I get:

```
Link speed:                200000 Kbps
```

Why values are different?

From my research, I concluded, that `NetworkCapabilities` class doesn't actually MEASURE bandwidth - it just returns EXPECTED values for detected technology (WiFi, cellular, etc.). I guess, that `WiFiInfo` does the same thing. I ran the code many times during extended period of time and got the same values you see above.

---

### Code

Here is the code with `NetworkCapabilities`:

```
val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(ConnectivityManager::class.java)    

val networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities?
            get() = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.activeNetwork)

    networkCapabilities?.linkDownstreamBandwidthKbps // 1048576
    networkCapabilities?.linkUpstreamBandwidthKbps   // 1048576
```

Here is the code with `WiFiInfo`:

```
val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(WifiManager::class.java)
wifiManager.connectionInfo.linkSpeed // returns 200 Mbps
```

Comment: probably `NetworkCapabilities` will return you the max link speed available for your device and connection type

Comment: So you are saying that there is a different link available except WiFi on my device that is faster than WiFi? I've checked available link types (`NetworkCapabilities.hasTransport(Int)`) and the only `true` I got was for `NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI`. Am I doing it right? Why google guys even call it "transport"? I think it should be "link" (as in OSI model).

Comment: WIFI of type AC is probably able to link to 1GBPS. Anyway that is just my guess

Comment: That's probably the case. Thanks for giving a lead on this.